# USB Type-C headphones detected on Catalina MacBook Pro with 2 or more minutes delay

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, usb, headphones

I have a pair of wired/corded USB Type-C AKG headphones.

When I plug them into the MacBook Pro's USB type C ports, they are visible (in the Sound Output preferences) only after about 2 minutes (measured several times). In this time, audio is not working via the USB type C headphones.

I did not observe any headphone detection patterns:

- at exact interval after plugging in (varying around 2 minutes)
- at exact minute change

The controls on the headphones wire work 5-10 seconds (play/pause, volume up, volume down) after plugging in.

After the about 2-minute interval, the Sound Output preference page appends the **USBC Headset** (Type: USB). No other audio devices are connected to the MabBook. Only the **Internal Speakers** (Type: Built-in) are available by default.

Is this a known/expected behaviour for MacBook Pros and USB Type-C headphones?

The devices I use:

- headphones: wired/corded AKG (cannot find the model name).
- computer: MacBook 2017 (with Touch Bar and also with 3.5mm audio port)

Comment: I can confirm the exact same behavior. M1 Macbook Air with AKG USB-C headphone that came with my Galaxy Z Flip phone. I takes about 2 minutes before the headphones are listed and start working.

Comment: Same here with Samsung/AKG headset (Feels like apple coded something to exclude other vendors: if(device.vendor.notEquals("Apple")) {delay(2, Minutes)} :-D )

Comment: Same issue with a 2021 MBP 14-inch and a Samsung headset.

Answer (score 1):

I would start diagnosing the issue using the IORegistryExplorer available as part of the "Hardware IO Tools for Xcode", which you can [get at Apple's](https://developer.apple.com/download/). If it shows up there but not in the System Preferences, I would hazard a guess that it's a driver issue. If it doesn't show up there, then I would think it's a hardware issue. Maybe also check the system logs for `coreaudiod`; the USB audio interface I use shows up within a second of being plugged in and prints all kind of info there.

In general, I've never had issues with USB audio devices on macOS over the last 15 years, and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/a16knn/usbc_headphones_not_working_with_macbook_pro/) reddit thread indicates that there are others with a similar issue with AKG headphones. You may just have made a bad purchase - which shouldn't be too bad if AKG still pretends to cater to professionals.

Best of luck!

Answer (score -2):

I just want to say brand new 2021 MacBook air when plugging in my wired USB-C AKG headphones; it takes 2 minutes to connect, once connected its OK but now, instead of waiting for dial-up to join, I plug in my headphones and make some coffee before returning to find them working lol.

Comment: This is not an answer but "I am having a similar problem" type of comment. Pls either revise it so that it answers the question or delete it altogether. If you wish to simply comment, pls wait until you have enough reputation points.